# Camel: strange convertBodyTo behaviour on different systems

Tags: mongodb, apache-camel, bson

this works on `oracle-7-jdk`, `icedtea-7-jdk` on `Gentoo linux kernel:  4.3.3-gentoo` :

```
     .marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)                                                                                                                                                                                                             
     .setBody().jsonpath("$.listing")                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    .process(new Processor(){                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
            @Override                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
            public void process(Exchange ex){                                                                                                                                                                                                         
                LinkedHashMap<String, Object> map = (LinkedHashMap)ex.getIn().getBody();                                                                                                                                                              
                map.put("_id", (Integer)map.get("id"));                                                                                                                                                                                               
                map.remove("id");                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
            }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
        })                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    .marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    .convertBodyTo(String.class)                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    .to("mongodb:mongoBean?database=myDB&collection=myCol&operation=save");
```

Same stuff does not work on `Ubuntu 14.4` under `openjdk-7-jre`
This stuff does not work either:

```
     .marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)                                                                                                                                                                                                             
     .setBody().jsonpath("$.listing")                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    .process(new Processor(){                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
            @Override                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
            public void process(Exchange ex){                                                                                                                                                                                                         
                LinkedHashMap<String, Object> map = (LinkedHashMap)ex.getIn().getBody();                                                                                                                                                              
                map.put("_id", (Integer)map.get("id"));                                                                                                                                                                                               
                map.remove("id");                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
            }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
        })                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    .marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    .convertBodyTo(String.class)                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    .bean(org.bson.Document.class, "parse(${body})")                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    .to("mongodb:mongoBean?database=myDB&collection=myCol&operation=save");
```

Consider I've added `.bean(org.bson.Document.class,"parse(${body})")` right before saving to Mongo.

What's the reason?

**UPDATE 1**

Using Camel `2.16.1`, no container.

1st code block throws:

```
Caused by: org.apache.camel.InvalidPayloadException: No body available of type: com.mongodb.DBObject but has value: {"city":"Los Angeles","distance":null,....
```

2nd code block throws:

```
 Caused by: org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException: No type converter available to convert from type: org.bson.Document to the required type: com.mongodb.DBObject
```

**UPDATE 2**

Final solution that works for me was:

```
     .marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)                                                                                                                                                                                                             
     .setBody().jsonpath("$.listing")                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    .process(new Processor(){                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
            @Override                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
            public void process(Exchange ex){                                                                                                                                                                                                         
                LinkedHashMap<String, Object> map = (LinkedHashMap)ex.getIn().getBody();                                                                                                                                                              
                map.put("_id", (Integer)map.get("id"));                                                                                                                                                                                               
                map.remove("id");                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

                Iterator<String> i = map.keySet().iterator();                                                                                                                                                                                         
                while(i.hasNext()){                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
                    String key = i.next();                                                                                                                                                                                                            
                    if(map.get(key) instanceof java.math.BigDecimal){                                                                                                                                                                                 
                        map.put(key, map.get(key).toString());                                                                                                                                                                                        
                    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
                }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
            }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
        })                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    .convertBodyTo(com.mongodb.DBObject.class)                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    .to("mongodb:mongoBean?database=airbnb&collection=appartments&operation=save");
```

as I received `No type converter available` for `java.math.BigDecimal`;

**UPDATE 3**

There was no difference between multiple environment. I assume that `mvn exec:java` worked but uberjar assembled with help of `maven-shade-plugin` did not due to some differences in component startup and (probably) type converter registrations.

Comment: What was the exception? Have you tried your 2nd code block on `oracle-7-jdk`, `icedtea-7-jdk`? What version of Camel are you using? In which container?

Comment: Sorry, put the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a `Map` in your body, you should be able to pass it directly to the `camel-mongodb` endpoint as the component perform the necessary type conversions to convert from:

- `Map` => `DBObject` (MongoDB's required type).
- `String` => `DBObject`.
- `File` => `DBObject`.
- `InputStream` => `DBObject`.
- Any other object => `DBObject` using Jackson to convert it to a `Map` first, and then to a `BasicDBObject`.

Check out the [available type conversions](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-mongodb/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/mongodb/converters/MongoDbBasicConverters.java).

Can you try and skip the marshalling to JSON and the `convertBodyTo`? Make sure you keep `camel-jackson` + dependencies in your classpath, though.

Comment: Just played with it but was getting another kind of problem. BigDecimal has no type converter by default. Improved abit, will put `UPD2` now.

Thank you.

Comment: Cool! Do you mean that Jackson doesn't have a serializer for BigDecimal?